# Flask app hangs when running with "host=0.0.0.0"

Tags: python, flask

I'm creating a small application on Flask which I want to access from a different device (Android). when I run Flask with localhost everything runs smoothly but when I change to "host=0.0.0.0" or "host=local IP" the app hangs. it seems the connection established because I see the following message:

```
> Restarting with stat  * Debugger is active!  * Debugger PIN:
> 467-361-115  * Running on all addresses.    WARNING: This is a
> development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.  *
> Running on http://10.142.131.160:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

but when I enter the URL nothing happens (it "loads" forever). I tried to:
1 - change the network to private
2 - add firewall inbound and outbound rules for TCP at the specific port
3 - turn off firewall on the network
4 - check Telenet on the port - looks like connection is fine
5 - run on two different networks (university wifi and hotspot)
6 - run from cmd and from pycharm

nothing helps... from similar questions it seems that it has to be with firewall but I really don't know what else can I do.
code -

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import csv
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

posts = [{'title': 'Welcome to Alpha Tau Treatment Server',
           'info': 'Here you will be able to post data that will be presented to the surgeon',
            'author': 'Made with Flask :)'
           }]


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route("/home", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return render_template("home.html", posts=posts)


@app.route("/data", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.form['csvfile']
        data = []
        with open(f) as file:
            csvfile = csv.reader(file)
            for row in csvfile:
                data.append(row)
        data = pd.DataFrame(data)
        return render_template("data.html", data=data.to_html(header='False', index=False))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

Answer (score 0):

**update**
for those of your that encounter similar problem, it seems that it was related to the browser (chrome). when I opened the server in incognito mode, that worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).